# How do I tell Visual Studio to stop being busy

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working with some clunky old (massive) Microsoft Access databases and, as a result, Visual Studio 2010 is regularly crashing on me.

When I try to use the Data Source Configuration Wizard it basically freezes and tells me that 'Visual Studio is Busy' and then doesn't come back. Not only this, but it locks the Access database.

I've tried Ctrl + Break and Ctrl + End with no joy, I always have to kill it with task manager, and I lose anything I haven't Saved/Commited since my last build!

Does anybody know of a more eloquent way of telling Visual Studio that you've changed your mind?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, when it says it's busy, you can't interrupt it. It might be a problem with your installation. Did you try it on a freshly installed Windows + Visual Studio?
Another thing you can try is download Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview and see if they have fixed the stability issue.